# How to post parameter using Volley library in android?

Tags: android

How can we post parameters using Volley library ? I have tried a lot but i could not get the solution . so if anyone knows how to post parameters using volley then please help me .

Comment: which type of param would you like to post?

Comment: i want to post email amd password using post method in android....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your custom request singleton that extends import `com.android.volley.Request` like this (in this case it's JSON but you can use string):

```
public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
                         Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                         Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    };

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("param1",string1);
                params.put("param2", "string2");
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, BuildConfig.API_HOSTNAME_JSON_POST,
                        params,  reponseListener, errorListener);
requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: could you please  tell me why it is  showing null values in this case .http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: I don't know if that API where values are post actually work?

Comment: this is the api i used ...  http://infowiz.in/workforce/login

Comment: Have you tested the above code i posted?

Comment: Thanks  i am able  to post now .. thanks

Comment: Can you mark answer as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to create a custom class that extends Volley's Request<> class...inside this class you should declare a constructor with the method you use to make the request(in your case POST), the url endpoint, the specific params you would like to post, and the Volley callback listeners. Also you have to create a method to get the post params which will be set and send from your activity of fragment

```
   public class MyRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {
          private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
          private Map<String, String> reponseListener;

          public MYRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params, Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
             super(method, url, errorListener);
             this.reponseListener = reponseListener;
             this.params = params;
          }

         protected Map<String, String> getParams()
             throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
         return params;
         }

         @Override
       protected Response<JSONObject>  parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
try {
    String jsonString = new String(response.data,
            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
    return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
            HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
} catch (JSONException je) {
    return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
}
 }

 @Override
 protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    responselistener.onResponse(response);
   }
  }

   }
```

you can call this class from your acctivity like this:

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    MyRequest jsObjRequest = new MyRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("RESPONSE ERROR", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

where params hash is:

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
       params.put("email", "yourEmail");
       params.put("password", "yourPassword");
```

Comment: if you do not want to use a singleton pattern to instansiate RequestQueue you could simply do: RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

Comment: Thanks code is working fine  now.....

Comment: you could accept my answer if you like...